# How to extract FASTA sequences from a file using sequence IDs in adifferent file?

Tags: perl, fasta

I have two files:

`sequence.fasta` - a big file with multiple FASTA sequences

`ids.txt` - consisting of sequence IDs in a tab-delimited format.

I want to extract those sequences into another file from `sequence.fasta` whose IDs matched in `ids.txt`.

A sample of `sequence.fasta`

```
>AUP4056.1
MFKSLIQFFKSKSNTSNIKKENAVQRQERQDIEGWITPYSGQELLNTELRQHHLGLLWQQVSMTREMFEH
LYQKPIERYAEMVQLLPASESHHHSHLGGMLDHGLEVISFAAKLRQNYVLPLNAAPEDQAKQKDAWTAAV
IYLALVHDIGKSIVDIEIQLQDGKRWLAWHGIPTLPYKFRYIKQRDYELHPVLGGFIANQLIAKETFDWL
ATYPEVFSALMYAMAGHYDKANVLAEIVQKADQNSVALALGGDITKLVQKPVISFAKQLI`

>XIM5213.2
FKISSKGPGDGWLTEDGLWLMSKTTADQIRAYLMGQGISVPSDNRKLFDEMQAHRVIESTSEGNAIWYCQ
LSADAGWKPKDKFSLLRIKPEVIWDNIDDRPELFAGTICVVEKENEAEEKISNTVNEVQDTVPINKKENI
ELTSNLQEENTALQSLNPSQNPEVVVENCDNNSVDFLLNMFSDNNEQQVMNIPSADAEAGTTMILKSEPE
NLNTHIEVEANAIPKLPTNDDTHLKSEGQKFVDWLKD
```

A sample of `ids.txt`

```
AUP4056.1 GUP5213.2 ARD5364.5 HAE6893.7
JIK6023.5 YUP7086.9
```

I need output as follows

```
>AUP4056.1
MFKSLIQFFKSKSNTSNIKKENAVQRQERQDIEGWITPYSGQELLNTELRQHHLGLLWQQVSMTREMFEH
LYQKPIERYAEMVQLLPASESHHHSHLGGMLDHGLEVISFAAKLRQNYVLPLNAAPEDQAKQKDAWTAAV
IYLALVHDIGKSIVDIEIQLQDGKRWLAWHGIPTLPYKFRYIKQRDYELHPVLGGFIANQLIAKETFDWL
ATYPEVFSALMYAMAGHYDKANVLAEIVQKADQNSVALALGGDITKLVQKPVISFAKQLI

>GUP5213.2
ELTSNLQEENTALQSLNPSQNPEVVVENCDNNSVDFLLNMFSDNNEQQVMNIPSADAEAGTTMILKSEPE
NLNTHIEVEANAIPKLPTNDDTHLKSEGQKFVDWLKDKLFKKQLTFNDRTAKVHIVNDCLFIVSPSSFEL
YLQEKGESYDEECINNLQYEFQALGLHRKRIIKNDTINFWRCKVIGPKKESFLVGYLVPNTRLFFGDKIL
INNRHLLLEE
```

I have tried a Perl one-liner, but this is not working. Neither giving any error nor any output.

```
perl -ne 'if(/^>(\S+)/){$c=$i{$1}}$c?print:chomp;$i{$_}=1 if @ARGV' ids.txt sequence.fasta
```

Could anybody help me correct this code or if there is any other Perl script?

Comment: Please show a few sample lines of input files, and the desired output

Comment: Are there really blank lines between the sequences in the FASTA file?

Comment: How is `>GUP5213.2` in your output produced when it's not in your `sequence.fasta` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that one-liners are very hard to follow, understand and untangle.

So write it out 'long hand':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $id_file, '<', 'ids.txt' ) or die $!;
#use split here, to split any lines on whitespace. 
chomp ( my @ids = map { split } <$id_file> );
close ( $id_file );

my %sequences;

open ( my $input, '<', 'sequence.fasta' ) or die $!;
{
   local $/ = '';    #paragraph mode; Read until blank line

   while ( <$input> ) {
      my ( $id, $sequence ) = m/>\s*(\S+)\n(.*)/ms;
      $sequences{$id} = $sequence;
   }
}

foreach my $id (@ids) {
   if ( $sequences{$id} ) {
      print ">$id\n";
      print "$sequences{$id}\n";
   }
}
```

If you want to read the filenames from `@ARGV`:

```
my ( $ids_file, $sequence_file ) = @ARGV;
```

I wouldn't try and compress this back into a one liner - you probably could, but it'll be quite hard to understand when you come back to it.

Comment: I suspect the FASTA file is actually contiguous without any blank lines.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answers @kjetil and Sobrique. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

If a one liner is what you want - which your post in fact suggests - this is what you could do:

```
perl -pe '$i=$1if/^>(\S+)/;map$i{$_}++,split;$i{$i}or$_=""' ids.txt seq.fasta
```

Comment: If you want to "have fun" with one-liners then please do it without the help of the rest of us who prefer clear code.

Comment: If you make announcements like that then inexperienced people like **user8392790** will think, *"This guy with over 700 times my experience says that one-liners are* fun, *and starts asking us all to help him to be involved in this fun"*. We then have to persuade him otherwise. It's irresponsible.