# Extract FASTA sequences from a file based on sequence IDs

Tags: perl, fasta

I have two files. `seq.fasta` consists of FASTA sequences and `ids.txt` contains IDs for sequences to extract from `seq.fasta`

For example

#### seq.fasta

```
>AUP4056.1
MFKSLIQFFKSKSNTSNIKKENAVQRQERQDIEGWITPYSGQELLNTELRQHHLGLLWQQVSMTREMFEH
LYQKPIERYAEMVQLLPASESHHHSHLGGMLDHGLEVISFAAKLRQNYVLPLNAAPEDQAKQKDAWTAAV
IYLALVHDIGKSIVDIEIQLQDGKRWLAWHGIPTLPYKFRYIKQRDYELHPVLGGFIANQLIAKETFDWL
ATYPEVFSALMYAMAGHYDKANVLAEIVQKADQNSVALALGGDITKLVQKPVISFAKQLI`
>XIM5213
FKISSKGPGDGWLTEDGLWLMSKTTADQIRAYLMGQGISVPSDNRKLFDEMQAHRVIESTSEGNAIWYCQ
LSADAGWKPKDKFSLLRIKPEVIWDNIDDRPELFAGTICVVEKENEAEEKISNTVNEVQDTVPINKKENI
ELTSNLQEENTALQSLNPSQNPEVVVENCDNNSVDFLLNMFSDNNEQQVMNIPSADAEAGTTMILKSEPE
NLNTHIEVEANAIPKLPTNDDTHLKSEGQKFVDWLKD
>bcna2598.1
GPGDGWLTEDGLWLMSKTTADQIRAYLMGQGISVPSDNRKLFDEMQAHRVIESTSEGNAIWYCQ
LSADAGWKPKDKFSLLRIKPEVIWDNIDDRPELFAGTICVVEKENEAEEKISNTVNEVQDTVPINKKENI
ELTSNLQEENTALQSLNPSQNPEVVVENCLPTNDDTHLKSEGQK
```

#### ids.txt

```
AUP4056.1 bcna2598.1 YUP42568 CAD42579.3 
JIK6023.5 ZNB708645
```

I tried the following program provided as an answer to
[*How to extract FASTA sequences from a file using sequence IDs in a different file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487007/how-to-extract-fasta-sequences-from-a-file-using-sequence-ids-in-adifferent-file)
but it just copies the `seq.fasta` file to the output.

#### Perl code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $id_file, '<', 'ids.txt' ) or die $!;
#use split here, to split any lines on whitespace. 
chomp ( my @ids = map { split } <$id_file> );
close ( $id_file );

my %sequences;

open ( my $input, '<', 'seq.fasta' ) or die $!;

{
   local $/ = '';    #paragraph mode; Read until blank line

   while ( <$input> ) {
      my ( $id, $sequence ) = m/>\s*(\S+)\n(.*)/ms;
      $sequences{$id} = $sequence;
   }
}

foreach my $id ( @ids ) {

   if ( $sequences{$id} ) {
      print ">$id\n";
      print "$sequences{$id}\n";
   }
}

close ($input);
exit;
```

Could anybody please tell me where I have gone wrong?

#### UPDATE:

I want to store the output in a separate file.

Comment: Read your own comments: `#paragraph mode; Read until blank line`. Your input has no blank lines, so `<$input>` reads the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're using is for a FASTA file that has blank lines between the sequences. Yours does not so it fails

This should work correctly, although I'm not in a position to test it

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %ids = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'ids.txt'
            or die qq{Unable to open "ids.txt" for input: $!};
    local $/;
    map { $_ => undef } split ' ', <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'seq.fasta'
        or die qq{Unable to open "seq.fasta" for input: $!};

my $print;
while ( <$fh> ) {
    $print = exists $ids{$1} if /^>(\S+)/;
    print if $print;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I direct the output to a file?